# Enter to elements of a Json object with php

Tags: arrays, json

I've got the following json object:

```
$dati = array(
    "data" => array(
        'address_complete'=>$data->results[0]->formatted_address, 
        'address_square'=>$data->results[0]->address_components[1]->long_name,
        'location'=>$data->results[0]->address_components[2]->long_name,
        'postal_code'=>$data->results[0]->address_components[7]->long_name,
        'data_ora'=>$tmp_date
    ),
    "str" => array ("n1"=>"fabio",
                    "n2"=>"marcolino",
                    "n3"=>"lauretta")
);
$p =  json_encode($dati);
echo $p;
```

How can I enter the `n1` element to show `fabio` as output?

`$p.str.n1` doesn't work. How can I do this?

Besides, how can I show `fabio`,`marcolino`,`lauretta` using a `for` loop?

```
for ($i=1; $i<=3; $i++) {
    $dati = array(
      "data" => array(
        'address_complete'=>$data->results[0]->formatted_address, 
        'address_square'=>$data->results[0]->address_components[1]->long_name,
        'location'=>$data->results[0]->address_components[2]->long_name,
        'postal_code'=>$data->results[0]->address_components[7]->long_name,
        'data_ora'=>$tmp_date
      ),
      "str" => array (
        "n".$i=>"fabio",
        "n".$i=>"marcolino",
        "n".$i=>"lauretta") 
    );
    //$p =  json_encode($dati);
    echo $dati[str]["n".$i];
}
```

How can I fix this code?

---

Finally I've got another question: if `"str" => array ("n1"=>"fabio", "n2"=>"marcolino", "n3"=>"lauretta")` are saved in a database and I want to get them from it, is correct to write in the following way?

```
"str" => array("n".$i=>"Ti sei incrociato con ".$array_db[username]),
```

and to call them with Ajax:

```
... success:function(msg){
        if(msg){
           $("#location").html(Object.keys(msg.str).map(x => msg.str[x]).join(", "));
        }else{
            $("#location").html('Not Available');
        }
```

Comment: Use `$dati` instead: `$dati["str"]["n1"]`. Once encoded, PHP treats this like a plain string. [Read more](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/php/617/json#t=201607231142558164482) about JSON

Comment: Thanks, I've got another question, so I edit my question above. @RuslanBes

Comment: Edited the code formatting. It's always good to reference variables from your code block with backticks --> `

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Besides How can I show "fabio","marcolino","lauretta" using a loop
>   for?

```
<?php 

$dati = array(
    "data" => array(
        'address_complete'=>$data->results[0]->formatted_address, 
        'address_square'=>$data->results[0]->address_components[1]->long_name,
        'location'=>$data->results[0]->address_components[2]->long_name,
        'postal_code'=>$data->results[0]->address_components[7]->long_name,
        'data_ora'=>$tmp_date
    ),
    "str" => array ("n1"=>"fabio",
                    "n2"=>"marcolino",
                    "n3"=>"lauretta")
);
?>

<script type="text/javascript">
<?="var p = " . json_encode($dati) ?>

// print individual elements
for (i in p.str) {
     console.log(p.str[i])
}

// print together
console.log(Object.keys(p.str).map(x => p.str[x]).join(", "))

</script>
```

Comment: How can I write `echo implode(', ', $dati["str"]);` using Jquery after an encoding? @RuslanBes

Comment: I've got a latest question so I updated the question above. @RuslanBes